# UIView not rendered in correct position in design mode in Storyboard

Tags: ios, autolayout, swift3

I created a UIView in this [WOWRibbonView project](https://github.com/zhouhao27/WOWRibbonView). It's working well when I run the application.

[image]

But it's not in correct position sometimes in Storyboard. I think it's an Autolayout related issue. But don't know the exact cause.

[image]

The full source code for the component is [here](https://github.com/zhouhao27/WOWRibbonView/blob/master/WOWRibbonView/src/WOWRibbonView.swift).

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the view interprets `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` differently at run time and design time. There was a session at RWDevCon last year that showed how to handle this. If you can't find it, I can probably look it up tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Its live views that renders content at design time. But autolayout us a runtime process.
Hence at design time live views render themselves but their positions that is controlled by  auto layout happens only at runtime .
[link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Interface_Builder_Live_Views_and_iOS_8_Embedded_Frameworks)
On mobile now. I will add more relevant links soon.